# Fast way to select n items (drawn from a Poisson distribution) for each element in array x

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I am having some trouble with solving a problem I encountered.

I have an array with prices:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
array([6, 1, 7, 6, 9, 0, 8, 2, 1, 8])
```

And a (randomly) generated array of Poisson distributed arrivals:

```
>>> arrivals = np.random.poisson(1, size=10)
array([4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
```

Each single arrival should be associated with the price at the same index. So in the case above, the first element ( x[0] ) should be selected 4 times ( y[0] ). The second element ( x[1] ) should be selected 0 times ( y[1] )...  The result thus should be:

```
array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 8, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 8])
```

Is there any (fast) way to accomplish this, without iterating over the arrays? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure whether this is fast, but at least it's short: `array(sum(map(lambda x, a: [x]*a, x, arrivals)))`

Comment: How are you going to use the resultant array? For some purposes, the *next* calculation can be achieved without forming this intermediate array. See for example, [scipy.stats.binned_statistic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html#scipy-stats-binned-statistic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [np.repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [43]: x = np.array([6, 1, 7, 6, 9, 0, 8, 2, 1, 8])

In [44]: arrivals = np.array([4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])

In [45]: np.repeat(x, arrivals)
Out[45]: array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 8, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 8])
```

but note that for certain calculations, it might be possible to avoid having to form this intermediate array. See for example, [scipy.stats.binned_statistic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

Comment: Dang, just as I finished writing up my answer. I should have known that this is already implemented in `numpy`, as always. :-) +1

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I will look further into solving the problem without having to form the whole intermediate array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how you could do that without looping at all.
What you could do is create the result array prior to looping; that way you don't need to concatenate afterwards.

```
Result = np.empty( arrivals.sum(), dtype='i' )
```

and then change the values of that array blockwise:

```
Result_position = np.r_[ [0], arrivals.cumsum() ]
for i, xx in enumerate(x):
    Result[ Result_position[i]:Result_position[i+1] ] = xx
```